# Bypassing a VPN

Tags: privacy, vpn

My friend (who is in college for some cyber security major) mentioned to me that it is possible to get a real IP through a VPN, and he's done it himself a few times. I myself use a VPN and although my VPN company has assured me that it's not possible, it certainly seems like if you are educated enough in that area it would be easy to bypass the VPN. What steps can I take to prevent this from happening to me?

Comment: He is probably talking about the WebRTC internal ip leak

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the configuration, the client ip can sometimes be traced. However if you setup a VPN tunnel, configured the VPN as gateway, and the network filter masquerades the outgoing traffic on the server, this ought not to happen.

There are services which let you connect to a proxy *over* VPN. This is different, because now the **proxy** must strip some headers (X-Forwarded-For, HTTP_CLIENT_IP and a handful more) it order to guarantee the anonymity. I am not sure if this is *'bypassing the VPN'*, but it certainly leaks your private info.

Answer (score 0):

What you refer to as a VPN is really an anonymizing proxy. A real vpn encapsulates traffic between two network nodes - the term "real ip" is somewhat irrelevant in that context.

In the case of an anonymizing proxy, these can be subverted by getting the client to make a network call to a monitored service without going through the vpn. Simply including a http or htps url with a non-standard port is enough to get around some such services. Embedding a network client in a web page, using activeX, flash or java it's possible to make a network call bypassing the browser's proxy settings. Its also possible to read the locally configured ip address [using a java applet](http://blog.jeremiahgrossman.com/2007/01/goodbye-applet-hello-nated-ip-address.html).

If you are sitting behind a nat router (as most of us are) then the latter is unlikely to be of any benefit to someone seeking to uncover your identity. Similarly, on a true VPN, other than the case of a tunnelled bridge, you are unlikely to be using an assigned ipv4 address. But if we are just talking about an anonymizing proxy, then it depends on how the service and your local machine are confgured as to how exposed you may be.